# Are there any functions involving these operators that have 'messy' undefined limits?

Tags: limits

Given ONLY the functions of addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, exponentiation, floor, modulo, summation, and the large product operator:

Can any function whatsoever be constructed that has an undefined limit purely due to extreme infinite "messiness" around the point of which the limit is being taken.

Comment: Messy like $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin(1/x)$ or what do you mean?

Comment: @AlexisOlson messy limits is a well defined term but yes that is what I mean.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Perhaps you could link to the definition then as a quick search doesn't find anything relevant.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillation_(mathematics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, there are many such functions.  A simple example is $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\rfloor.$$  As $x$ approaches $0$, $f(x)$ oscillates between $0$ and $1$ infinitely many times.